# Give all divs the same height and width with dynamic data

Tags: html, css

In the image below you can see the 3rd boxes height is different from the first 2. Thats because of the text inside is longer then the first 2.

[image]

Is it possible to keep the height and width of the boxes the same with different lengths of text. The text should also be centred and longer text should go on multiple lines.

Link to the CodePen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbgKEb

```
<form>
    <div id="test"><label><input class="test" type="checkbox" /> This is a practice</label></div>
    <div id="test"> <label><input class="test" type="checkbox" /> This si another practice</label></div>
    <div id="test"> <label><input class="test" type="checkbox" /> Practice practice practice</label></div>

</form>
```

Comment: I'd look into using flexbox!

Comment: @Benneb10 When the `width` and `height` are already defined, I don't go for that overkilling flexbox!

Comment: Please note that each individual value for `id` can occur only once per document.

Comment: Do you need to support IE9 and less and Android 4.3.x or less? If not, flexbox is way more _agile_ (and compatible with IE10+, Android 4.4+)

Comment: OT: You should add an `id` attribute on each input with the same value as the value of label@for, that is `<label for="prac1"><input id="prac1">`. More explanations and examples in [Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls (H44)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html) (WCAG 2.0)

Comment: Sidenote: Funny how none of the given answers correct the obvious typo in the second container's text :D

Comment: @FelipeAls What you recommend is good to know for sure, but in this case the same goal is reached by *wrapping* the `input` with the `label`.

Comment: @connexo Granted, it's now [compatible with screen readers](http://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/input-text-implicit-label-before/). A while ago, screen readers were dumb enough not to understand that a parent label was the associated label of a form field or checkbox/radio.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't duplicate `ID`s. That's a crime.** Use `vertical-align: middle` to solve your problem.

```css
label {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:  150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="checkbox"].test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="test">
      <label>
        <input class="test" type="checkbox" />This is a practice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <label>
        <input class="test" type="checkbox" />This si another practice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <label>
        <input class="test" type="checkbox" />Practice practice practice</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Preview**

[image: Preview]

**Note:** When the `width` and `height` are already defined, I don't go for that overkilling flexbox! If someone advises to use `flexbox`.

If you need the vertical aligning to be centered, instead of `inline-block`, use `table-cell` and it fixes it.

```css
label {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:  150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"].test-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="test">
      <label>
        <input class="test-input" type="checkbox" />This is a practice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <label>
        <input class="test-input" type="checkbox" />This si another practice</label>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <label>
        <input class="test-input" type="checkbox" />Practice practice practice</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Preview**

[image: udpated]

Comment: OP asked to center text vertically.

Comment: @connexo I can add a text centering stuff. No problem.

Comment: Curious to see how you're planning to achieve that insisting on `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: @connexo Now don't corner me. `:(`

Comment: Please don't use quoting functionality for highlighting portions of your text.

Comment: @connexo Done both. Any comments? `:)`

Comment: Not sure if I'd prefer `display: table-cell;` over using flexbox. Your method has it's downsides as well (which I assume you know when advising `display: table-cell;`). Also, I wouldn't use `.test` for both the `div` and the checkbox.

Comment: @connexo Agreed with you on this.

Comment: @connexo Updated as requested as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** with applying only one property `display: flex;`, use `align-items: center` to make it align vertically center & `justify-content: center` to make it horizontally center. Like:

```css
.test-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {  
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:  150px;
  height: 200px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="test-holder">
    <div class="test"><label><input class="test" type="checkbox" /> This is a practice</label></div>
   <div class="test"> <label><input class="test" type="checkbox" /> This is another practice</label></div>
   <div class="test"> <label><input class="test" type="checkbox" /> Practice practice practice</label></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please do note that the OP has used fixed dimensions. Now we don't need flexbox layout. `:)` Just telling, as I commented the same in the question as well as in my answer. Looks like you failed to notice.

Comment: So far this is not a complete solution since it neither centers text vertically nor horizontally. Also, I wouldn't use `.test` for both the `div` and the checkbox.

Comment: @connexo It is now aligned.

Comment: From what I see at least the first label is not centered horizontally.

Comment: @connexo Have a look at my updated answer. I used `justify-content: center`